# Two-sample bootstrap hypothesis test

Tags: python, sampling, bootstrap

I am a beginner so please be indulgent.

I would like to use a two-sample bootstrap hypothesis test for difference of means to this scenario:  the impact of a new tool on team members daily output (output is count data, an integer that rarely exceeds 100 and not normally distributed). All the data produced is stored in a database, and I have over 1 year of pre-data and 3 months of post-data (pre = before new tool).

So I have a dataset that looks like this:

UserName - Date (e.g. 11/10/2017) - Output (Integer min 1, max 150 ) - Pre/Post label (before the tool adoption everything is labeled pre, after everything is labeled post, ~20 different users )

My hypothesis is the following:

$H_0$: Mean Post = Mean Pre

$H_1$: Mean Post <> Mean Pre

Q1: Is this a valid approach?

```
#Get empirical difference of means, diff_of_mean functions returns
#np.mean(a)- np.mean(b) 
empirical_diff_means = diff_of_means(postdata,predata)

# Here the part I am not sure about, how should I determine the sample?
sample_post = np.random.choice(postdata, 50) 
sample_pre =  np.random.choice(predata, 50)

#Concatenate and shift the pre and post data to test the null hypothesis
samples_concat = np.concatenate((sample_post,sample_pre))
mean_concat = np.mean(samples_concat)

# Generate shifted arrays
sample_post_shifted = sample_post - np.mean(sample_post) + mean_concat 
sample_pre_shifted = sample_pre - np.mean(sample_pre) + mean_concat 

# Compute 10,000 bootstrap replicates of the mean from shifted arrays 
bs_replicates_a = draw_bs_reps(sample_post_shifted, np.mean, size=10000)
bs_replicates_b = draw_bs_reps(sample_pre_shifted, np.mean, size=10000)

# Get replicates of difference of means: bs_replicates
bs_replicates = bs_replicates_a-bs_replicates_b

# Compute and print p-value: p
p = np.sum(bs_replicates >= empirical_diff_means) / len(bs_replicates)
conf_int=np.percentile(bs_replicates,[2.5,97.5])
print('p-value =', p)
print('95% Confidence Interval =' ,[2.5,97.5])
```

Comment: Why do a bootstrap?

Comment: @user2974951, which approach would you use? The reasons I can think are: a) the data is not normally distributed. b) Although we store all the data, the number of people in the team is relatively small. c) It is easier -for me- to explain and to code the bootstrap procedure (I have learned it in a course, as I said I am a beginner).

Comment: You don't specify which test you are using to check the means so I'm going to assume it's a t-test. If the assumptions of the t-test are not met (ugly data) you can always use a non-parametric test which has few assumptions such as the Welch test.